# Angular2 - Router does not pick up route/home path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have and Angular2 app using this [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).  I just added a fallback route to my `app.routes.ts` file after adding its module (`NotFoundModule`) to `app.module.ts` and everything works great except now my home path(`''`) does not register anymore and the `NotFoundComponent` loads.  The code is below:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';

import { DataResolver } from './app.resolver';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
     path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
     path: 'getstarted', loadChildren: './getstarted#GetStartedModule'
  },
  {
     path: 'open-account', loadChildren: './open-account/#OpenAccountModule'
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
  {
    path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
  },
];
```

How can I fix this problem so my Home route will work properly again and the `NotFoundComponent` won't load in its place?

Comment: I'm not sure but try adding { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: ` { path: '**', redirectTo: ['NotFoundComponent']}`

Comment: post some fiddle

Comment: whats the url you trying hit? like localhost? copy and past the url you are attempting to get to

Answer (score 1):

When you have routes that use `''` for their path and don't have children, you'll want to specify `pathMatch: 'full'` for that route.

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
     path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  {
     path: 'getstarted', loadChildren: './getstarted#GetStartedModule'
  },
  {
     path: 'open-account', loadChildren: './open-account/#OpenAccountModule'
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
  {
    path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
  },
];
```

See https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html#!#matching-strategy for the reasoning.

Comment: { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },